# Unix bash assigning string with spaces to a variable

Tags: bash

I am facing issue while assigning sting with spaces to variable. Below is my command.

`test.ksh` should accept "remove file" as one variable. But I am unable to do so.

```
hello="/export/appl/<userid>/test.ksh remove file"
$hello
```

Comment: You do not assign a command in a variable and later you execute it, use a `function` instead. If you just want to capture the output then use `$( )` instead of double quotes. Also `remove` and `file` are two different words, how does it become one word? quote it `'remove file'` , but I suggest you try https://shellcheck.net and re think the logic of what are you trying to solve.

Comment: Hello ‘remove file’ this is two word but when I pass to test.ksh I take it as eval $1 so I could use remove as function file as variable passed to that function .

Comment: @user13377293 Warning: `eval` has a well-deserved reputation as a source of confusing and dangerous bugs. In my experience, if `eval` looks like a good idea, that's generally a sign that you should rethink what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jetchisel mentionned, you should quote your string that contains spaces otherwise it will be interpreted as separated value (`$1=remove` and `$2=file` ). Moreover by looking what you want to achieve, I would suggest to use command substitution:

```sh
hello=$(/export/appl//test.ksh "remove file")
```